# Is it a good practice to re-throw exceptions through all the nested functions until the main() function is reached?

Tags: c++

Like in the topic of my question;

***Is it a good practice to re-throw exceptions through all the nested functions until the main() function is reached?***

Let's say that upon a single run-time-error(user fault or anything else) in my application I want to kill entire program. Is is a good practice to do the following:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func_1(void) {
    cout << "I am in func_1()" << endl;
    cout << "- Throwing exception" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    throw std::runtime_error("ERROR !!!");
}

void func_2(void) {
    try {
        cout << "I am in func_2()" << endl;
        cout << "- Trying func_1()..." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        func_1();
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error & error){
        cout << "I am in func_2()" << endl;
        cout << "- Re-throwing exception." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        throw error;
    }
}

void func_3(void) {
    try {
        cout << "I am in func_3()" << endl;
        cout << "- Trying func_2()..." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        func_2();
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error & error) {
        cout << "I am in func_3()" << endl;
        cout << "- Re-throwing exception." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        throw error;
    }
}

int main() {
    try {
        cout << "I am in main()" << endl;
        cout << "- Trying func_3()..." << endl;
        cout << endl;
        func_3();
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error error) {
        cout << "I am in main()" << endl;
        cout << "- Catching func_3() exception..." << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }

    // Exit:
    getchar();
}
```

---

The code above is my alternative to `exit()`. But to be honest, the code management, is horrendous. **Therefor is it a good or bad practice**?

---

Also I am not sure about performance overhead... I know that I just said I want to perform safe-exit from my program in case of any error, therefore performance 
is not an issue.

But what if, at some point I will change my mind and write code that will be able to recover from an error?

Let's say that `n-functions` have to `re-throw` my exception before it will be `catch'ed` and handled? **What kind of performance overhead I have to expect**?

Comment: Eeek, please get all that comment '///' and blank line noise out of the question.  As for your question "upon a single run-time-error(user fault or anything else) in my application I want to kill entire program" then just let the exception propagate and it will kill the application - you don't need to do anything. And *no*; *don't* `catch` and re-`throw` everywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're even trying this. If you *don't* catch and re-throw the exceptions in `func_2` and `func_3` the exception will equally get back to `main`. I'm guessing the printing of messages is just for demonstration purposes, so what's the problem you're trying to solve with the additional catch blocks?

Comment: It is horrendous... Where did you get the idea that you need to catch and rethrow exception everywhere?

Comment: This is a completely artificial example..  impossible to tell whether you're doing the right thing TM.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, Sorry for that comment noise. It's gone.

Comment: Why do you even have so many `catch`es?  Most functions can let the exception just pass straight through to an eventual handler, assuming you use RAII correctly.

Comment: @aschepler if i create my custom exception class and `throw` it from `func_1()`,  then `catch` it in `main()` my program triggers a breakpoint due to not handled exception. That was the only solution, that i could came up with.

Comment: make sure the the exception class is derived from std::exception if you catch a std::exception within you main(). Also note that you should catch exceptions by const-reference.

Comment: @TheTechel My exception is derived from `std::runtime_error`. (is it the same?) Yet it still triggers a breakpoint.

Comment: @cukier9a7b5: then please show your REAL code that is not working for you. And BTW, note that the *correct* way to re-throw a caught exception is to call `throw` by itself without any parameter at all, eg: `catch (std::runtime_error & error) { ... throw; }` DO NOT explicitly pass the caught exception object to `throw` again.  Calling `throw;` inside a `catch` block re-throws the current exception.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am sorry that i did not answer earlier. I have found out what was wrong in my code. I am a bit ashamed to admit, but I have been catching wrong exception type... Simple oversight... It was a result of putting `catch` block inside a macro. Thank you for your advice, I didn't know that calling `throw` without anything `re-throws` caught exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.  When your program gets large, you'll have to treat multiple exception throws in main, completely detached from their original context.

I try to keep everything as localized as possible, and within a certain context.  For example, if I have a few functions that handle opening a file, these might throw exceptions up until the first caller of the open_file call.  At that point, I either notify the user that the file in inaccessible/faulty/whatever.

In my main function, I have a `catch(...)` but only for logging purposes.  Any unhanded exception gets logged and the program exists with a terminal error.

Comment: Thank you, this question is about good programming practices, and your answer delivered me one.
In between, I have found out that I have missed something and there is an error, that forces me to put `catch` and `re-throw` everywhere in my code. Now for me its time to `debug`.

Comment: Are you using GDB?  You can set: `catch throw` in GDB's cmdline.  That will interrupt on any throw.  It helps me a _lot_ trying to find these kinds of bugs.

Comment: No, I am using visual studio 2015. But I am thinking about switching to Linux.